# In How many ways we can Resolve Heap Space issue in java?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, heap-memory

I know we can increase heap size by maximize these JVM variable -Xms, -Xmx.

But I have following doubt:

1. what are the other ways to handle Heap Space?
2. Is Heap Memory depends on the system secondary memory?

Comment: That's too many broad questions :)

Comment: yes @manouti, but I want to clear my JVM basics.

Comment: good questions friend, but maybe asking those in 4 new questions instead of a one question is better, or at least in two seperate questions. any way google it, I think you might find the answer

Comment: @niceman If you think it is a good question you can give an up vote and thanks for suggestions, I want the expert views on my doubt. If you have any useful link and answer, please post it.

Comment: sorry Surnet but I'm not an expert in heap things

Comment: Can you please explain what your second question means, or what you are referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what are the other ways to handle Heap Space?

There is about 500 options for controlling the heap ther most common ones are available here [Hotspot VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

> Is Heap Memory depends on the system secondary memory?

There is only main memory to worry about when it comes to the heap size.  The default heap size for a 64-bit JVM is 1/4 of main memory.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few points you need to look at when trying to setup your heap size in java, after a quick search I have found the following site that has some points on how JVM works in regards to heap:
http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/java-heap-space-memory-size-jvm.html

*obviously the Oracle java site should be your first point of call.

1) I don't think you can adjust the heap space dynamically during runtime. So setting it the start is a must.

2) Depends on if you are running a 32/64bit OS, and how much RAM you have on the PC

3) See link above and Oracle's own docs, it is too large to describe :)

4) Really depends on what you are programming and the resources you have on the PC. Good programming practices should stop any major problems, but if you find too many full GCs you might want to see if you don't have a "memory leak" somewhere in the Perm part of the heap

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your first question: using `java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()` you can allocate memory outside of the Heap, i.e. expand memory footprint at runtime.

From the Javadocs:

> The contents of direct buffers may reside outside of the normal garbage-collected heap, and so their impact upon the memory footprint of an application might not be obvious. It is therefore recommended that direct buffers be allocated primarily for large, long-lived buffers that are subject to the underlying system's native I/O operations. In general it is best to allocate direct buffers only when they yield a measureable gain in program performance.